# How do I check my lambda expression for null?

Tags: c#, lambda

If there are no records that match the following lambda query, I get a

> System.InvalidOperationException error. Additional information: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

The code is: `runTime = db.Records.Where(c => c.MachineDesc.Contains(strMachine) && c.ProductionDate == dt && c.Shift == x).Sum(c => c.RunMinutes);`

The variable `runTime` is a `decimal`. I tried changing it to a `decimal?` but I still get the same error.

What is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly you can select decimal values from the objects which met the condition. And then use [`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method before the `.Sum()` method:

```
runTime = db.Records
              .Where(c => c.MachineDesc.Contains(strMachine) && c.ProductionDate == dt && c.Shift == x)
              .Select(c => c.RunMinutes)
              .DefaultIfEmpty()
              .Sum();
```

`DefaultIfEmpty()` function inserts a single element with a default value if the sequence is empty. And as we know, defualt value for `decimal` type is `0.0M`.
[(Default Values Table)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)

***Additionally***:

You didn't tell us **Linq to *What*?** are you using. But, if you are using LinqToEntity, then you must change your code as (`DefaultIfEmpty` is not supported by EF):

```
runTime = db.Records
              .Where(c => c.MachineDesc.Contains(strMachine) && c.ProductionDate == dt && c.Shift == x)
              .Sum(c => (decimal?)c.RunMinutes) ?? 0;
```

Comment: @BillGreer Could you please tell us what is the error?

Comment: @BillGreer Also, tell us Linq to what are you using? Linq to Entity, Linq to Sql, Linq to Objects?

Comment: Linq to Entity.   I get a compile error:  'System.Linq.IQueryable<Record>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty'   How do I add a definition for DefaultIfEmpty?